# stretch image in imageview to fit screen in xml

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have image in drawable, which needs to work as the background. It needs to stretch to fill the screen..
I know how to stretch the image full screen using java code.. but in XML itselt how can do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`android:scaleType="fitXY"` will stretch the image to fit the full size of the `ImageView`

Answer (score 5):

Try with this property:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) you can find other constant values for resizing.

Answer (score 5):

Try to implement your ImageView like this and change the ***ic_launcher*** to your own image name which you are trying to add.

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Hope this will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use scaleType="centerCrop". This way the image isn't stretched out of its original proportions.